# Fedora 29 MongoDB Compass install Segmentation fault Core dump

Tags: mongodb, segmentation-fault, fedora, compass

I tried installing MongoDB Compass but got Segmentation fault core dump.

Installed an earlier version which got me up and running.

(1) `wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-1.14.1.x86_64.rpm`

(2) `sudo dnf install mongodb-compass-1.14.1.x86_64.rpm`

(2.5) `yes` to all

(3) `mongodb-compass`

So this is not a question as much it is a tip for you guys.
I'd be happy if anyone could explain to me why I got seg fault that be great.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I confirm this workaround works under Fedora 29. Note that the bug may be fixed now [1] but at this day, even the beta version still produces the core dump. [1] https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-2773

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually It's because of an error from `mongo compass` installation, for fedora 29 & 30 works the version **14.5.1**

You can install it with the next steps:

1. `su`
2. `cd /tmp`
3. `wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-1.14.5.x86_64.rpm`
4. `dnf install ./mongodb-compass-1.14.5.x86_64.rpm`
5. `mongodb-compass`